# How to add custom fee to woocommerce from a custom filed

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have added a custom text field (named `add_for_charity_field`) in woocommerce. This filed is for adding desired amount for charity. I have used the `WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor` plugin to adding this field in checkout form. Now I need to add this field content to cart by `add_fee` function but I don't have access to the field content in php. Is there a solution for it ? I am not familiar with jQuery and I think that I must use jQuery.

I have use this code in `function.php`

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {

     global $woocommerce;

     $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Charity', 'woocommerce'), $_POST['add_for_charity_field'] );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

Comment: This is much more complicated and advanced, as you will need to use php with Javascript and Ajax.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes. I am confused :|  Is there any solution to do this ?

Comment: There is mostly always a solution, but here it is something advanced and complicated, so a real development like, just too broad. Now I wish you that someone has already done something similar and will answer…